# Setting device twin tags using IoT hub DM API

Tags: device, iot

How do I set the TAGs of a device in the IoT Hub Device Management API's There doesnt seem to be a specific method for this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The (C#) sample in the SDK shows how to do this. You have to pick the correct branch for this to be included.

Here's the link:https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdks/tree/dmpreview

It deserializes a device object using this JSON: 
 {
      "deviceId": "Device11-7ce4a850",
      "serviceProperties": {
        "properties": {
          "CustomerId": "123456",
          "ServiceBy": "Contoso",
          "Weight": 1000,
          "QoS": 10
        },
        "tags": [ "milk", "cookies", "sausage", "bacon" ]
      }

and then passes it to the Registery Manager:

registryManager.AddDeviceAsync(device);

Comment: this URL doesn't work anymore, "All SDKs have now been moved in their own repositories". The new one for .NET is https://github.com/azure/azure-iot-sdk-csharp but I can't find references to the twin tags